Should the search bar go above or below the tabs here?

I have a search bar to search icons. And tabs to show types of icons.
Do you think the search bar should be above or below the tabs? If so, why?

You state that tabs show types of icons, but the tabs in the image aren’t types. Can you explain that?

Natural progression here would be:
Search Bar (Top) | Tabs (Middle) | Icons/Search Results (Bottom)
Flow of function would go something like this:

User types in Search Box, results show up accordingly in the bottom panel.
User can now navigate among the search results or filter results using the tabs available.

Suggestion: Change tabs to buttons. They are basically filters and usually buttons are used for filters. Also, tabs below Search bar will look unnatural and will not follow usual design patterns.

Agreed, but chips/tags would fit the interaction better than buttons, because these can be toggled on and off.
